# mysql query displays field data not matched to LIKE statement

Tags: php, mysql

I've been spending hours on this one.
So I got two tables, the "candidate_list" table and "election_title" table. I need to display all the candidates running in a certain election/club by matching the "ename" column on both tables. Also, it has an if while statement because it is highly dependent on admin input. Hope you can help me with this one.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "voting_system";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT ename FROM election_title ORDER BY `sdate` ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ename= $row['ename'];
?> 
<p><font size= "6px" align = "center" color = "#efbf77"> <?php echo $row['ename']. "<br>";?></p>

<?php

$servername1 = "localhost";
$username1 = "root";
$password1 = "";
$dbname1 = "voting_system";



$conn1 = new mysqli($servername1, $username1, $password1, $dbname1);


if ($conn1->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn1->connect_error);

} 


$sql = "SELECT * FROM candidate_list WHERE ename IN (SELECT ename FROM election_title);";
$result = $conn1->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ename= $row['ename'];
    $pos= $row['pos'];
    $fname= $row['fname'];
    $mname= $row['mname'];
    $lname= $row['lname'];


    ?> 
    <button type="submit" class = "ename"> <?php echo "<p class = 'bold'>" .$row['ename']. " </p>" .$row['pos']. "<br>" .$row['fname']. " " .$row['mname'] . " " .$row['lname'];?> </button>



<?php
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>
<?php
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

$conn1->close();

?>
```

As of now, it only display one election title. I need it to loop and display all my elections together with its respective candidates.

Comment: Bad code practices ;)

Comment: I just fragmented it from what i can get in some searches. Im literally just new in mysql

Comment: What's your question? as a rule of thumb, we shouldn't have to read the body of the question to figure out what you are asking. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Oh im sorry. This is my first question posted here. So bare with me. Im having problems with the looping of if and while statement in php echo. I have two sets of echo(retrieving data from mysql database). Im literally out of ideas now.

Comment: Firstly, you do not need to make the connection twice -- you only need 1 connection object. The second thing to try would be to name your $result and $row variables different things in the sub-loop so that they don't overwrite the variables set in the top loop.

Comment: I think you should use SQL joins.

Comment: @JoshuaKlein so i tried renaming my variables and the election titles already been displayed. I think it worked. But the candidates displayed are the just the same and dont match their club/org. So i think the problem now is in the query. Anyways, thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Did you try to run this query in MySQL workbench to see what it returns. Then only you can see if your PHP code is displaying the same.

Comment: @AllenKing ive tried the query with "LIKE %math%" and worked. Nothing is wrong with the query structure at first. So i realized i can only get the results that i want if i ran it in the program(because its dependent on the column name "ename") so i tried changing the query many times til i cant get other ideas anymore.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: The query has worked after some reading on INNER JOINS. Thanks for your help guys! :)